# Gridsplitter: limit row heights to window size

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, grid, gridsplitter

I have just started to experiment with gridsplitters and have stumbled across a very weird behaviour and I cannot seem to fix it. Apparently the others have similar issues (according to google), but there were no helpful comments.

I have a grid with 2 rows. On start up the bottom one has a `Hight` of 250. The top row takes the rest with `*`. When I resize the rows with the splitter the behaviour is as expected for the top row. But when I drag the splitter upwards and past the program window, the content of the bottom row will drop out of the window (=move downwards until it is gone). I'd expect that I cannot make each row larger than the parent container.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid_main" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="250"  Height="250"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="splitter" 
        ResizeDirection="Rows" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto"
        Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0" ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">              
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This is my code. The content of both rows is again hosted in grids and has been removed for the sake of simplicity. Again: Resizing for the top row works fine. But the bottom row can be resized to infinity. It works as expected if I hard-code a `MaxHeight`. But that has to depend on the window size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your second `RowDefinition` to the following:

```
<RowDefinition MinHeight="250" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=grid_main, Path=ActualHeight}" Height="250"/>
```

This will ensure that the row height will not exceed the window size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works. But implementing a `MinHeight` for the top row proves to be... difficult... When dealing with WPF I normally curse the sh*t out of it and at some point I have a really elegant solution that makes me think "Wow, WPF is really cool after all". Not sure I will reach this point on this subject though...

Comment: I know what you mean, I feel the same way a lot of the time.  There is a solution to defining a MinHeight for the top row, whether it is elegant or not is debatable!  If you use a MultiValueConverter you can pass it the ActualHeight of the Grid as before, and the top row MinHeight and return the difference. Use this value as your max height on the second row.

Comment: I used a `IValueConverter` to apply offset.

Answer (score 1):

Richard's solution didn't work for me (the ActualHeight of the grid expanded past the window size along with the row height).

Using Snoop, I found that the ActualHeight of an ancestor ContentPresenter wasn't increasing. Thus the following bottom row definition worked for me, although I was still seeing issues if I set MinHeight on either the top or bottom rows:

```
<RowDefinition Height="430"
               MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem only occurs because the second row has an absolute Height. If you actually want an absolute Height value try Richards's solution. Otherwise, just use a relative Height (e.g. 2*) on the second row as well.

Answer (score 0):

Grigory Zhadko's answer is good to me.

I had a problem with this code

```
gridBase.RowDefinitions[1].Height = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("1");
gridBase.RowDefinitions[3].Height = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("1");
```

and I fixed it like this

```
gridBase.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(0.1, GridUnitType.Star);
gridBase.RowDefinitions[3].Height = new GridLength(0.1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

and the grid converter works perfectly